# Error: could not find function "summaryBy" in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to get the summaryBy function to work but can't seem to get it on R. I have looked though various forums and used the tips given but still can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a novice to R so I may be making a simple error but I have tried to cover off all the suggestions from other forums. My code looks like this:

```
> install.packages("doBy", dependencies = TRUE)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Dechlan/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'http://star-www.st-andrews.ac.uk/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/doBy_4.5-10.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2634327 bytes (2.5 Mb)
opened URL
downloaded 2.5 Mb

package ‘doBy’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
     C:\Users\Dechlan\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqOhjyD\downloaded_packages
```

Then

```
> summaryBy(A, data = testdata2, id = good)
Error: could not find function "summaryBy"
> require(summaryBy)
Loading required package: summaryBy
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘summaryBy’
```

Can anyone see why it doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: you need `require(doBy)` (or `library("doBy")` or `library(doBy)` ...

Answer (score 1):

Remember, you installed a *package* called `doBy`, which includes a *function* called `summaryBy`. You install a package, you require a package, but you call a function.

So you should do:

```
install.packages("doBy")
require(doBy)            # note the difference!
summaryBy(...)
```

You can also use `library()` instead of `require()`. Either way works, though they differ in their response to packages that are not found. More [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/library.html).